# Get formatted time string for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, android, postgresql

I use a PostgreSQL database server. One column has "timestamp with time zone" and I upload time string through XML like '2012-07-11 04:45:18+GMT+05:30' but it accepts this format '2012-02-16 19:47:22.652+05:30'

So, how can I format the time string on Android? Below is my function.

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ");
Log.v("AKDN", "Time string is:"+formatter.format(c.getTime()));
return formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your question isn't quite clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: i want time string like '2012-02-16 19:47:22.652+05:30' in android.

Comment: Did you get it working the way you wanted it?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
private String getTime()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SZ");
    return formatter.format(c.getTime());
}
```

In my case it outputs:

```
2012-07-11 06:32:46.118-0600
```

**EDIT:**
You can either add the "**:**" to your string.

Or you can create another function to format the timezone. Something like this:

```
private String formatTimeZone(TimeZone tz)
{
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00");
    String timeZone = new String("");
    int offset = tz.getRawOffset();

    if(offset != 0)
    {
        int hours = Math.abs((offset / (60 * 1000)) / 60);
        int minutes = Math.abs((offset / (60 * 1000)) % 60);
        timeZone += offset < 0 ? "-" : "+";
        timeZone += format.format(hours);
        timeZone += ":";
        timeZone += format.format(minutes);
    }

    return timeZone;
}
```

Comment: this gives me output like '2012-07-11 06:21:14.624+0530' but actually i want like '2012-02-16 19:47:22.652+05:30'. 
There's no ':' in result string in '+0530'.